# Unexpected behaviour when _.allKeys(obj) array(say var arr) is referred to object :obj.arr[0], it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

For those who don't know what _.allKeys(obj) does, here's a snippet

```
var allKeys = function(obj){
          var key=[];
          for(var pname in obj){
          key.push(pname);              
          }
          return key;
        };`
```

So it returns an array of property/method names of an object which is passed to it.

```
//Say I have an object obj.
var obj={firstname:"John", lastname:"Adams"};
var arr=allKeys(obj);  //stores the returned array of property names into arr.
for(var i;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log("Property name: "+arr[i]); //this detects the propertyname
  console.log("Value name"+obj.arr[i]);  //But when its referred to the object it does not return its value,why so ?
  console.log("------");
}
```

This should give me:

> Property name: firstname 
>  
>   Value name: John 
>  
>   ------ 
>   Property name: lastname 
>  
>   Value name: Adams 
>  
>   ------

Instead it gives me :

> Property name: firstname 
>  
>   Value name: undefined 
>  
>   ------ 
>  
>                         Property name: lastname 
>  
>                         Value name: undefined 
>  
>                         ------

Any ideas why it does that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the same result as you expected

```js
var allKeys = function(obj){
          var key=[];
          for(var pname in obj){
          key.push(pname);              
          }
          return key;
        };

var obj={firstname:"John", lastname:"Adams"};
var arr=allKeys(obj);  //stores the returned array of property names into arr.
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log("Property name: "+arr[i]); //this detects the propertyname
  console.log("Value name: "+obj[arr[i]]); // I used BRACKET NOTATION
  console.log("------");
}
```

**[Ref](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)**

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow thanks, this is my first post on stackoverflow!
Could you tell me why '.' did not work ? Thank you so much :D

Comment: Just a duplicated post ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get value in this way. `.` and `[]` are both used to get value of certain key , but when key is a variable , you need `[]` , not `.` .

And if you just want to show keys and values , no need to do it in that complex way .

```
var obj={firstname:"John", lastname:"Adams"};
for(let key in obj){
    console.log("Property name: "+key); //this detects the propertyname
    console.log("Value name"+obj[key]);  
    console.log("------");
}
```

This is all you need .

Comment: Thanks a ton. How do I indirectly add a property name with a value through those arrays,without directly adding it into the object literal ?